# Disable Haproxy Logging messages

Tags: haproxy

I am having a problem with `haproxy`. Every time I turn off virtuoso, haproxy shows the following error message:

> Message from syslogd@master0 at Jul  9 14:39:18 ...  haproxy[4403]:
>   backend virtuoso has no server available!

I found the following [Link](http://marc.info/?l=haproxy&m=136964221703933)  where they suggested to use `*.emerg;local2.none Â *` but I really didn't undestand how it can help and where it should be located in the configuration file.

How can I modify the configuration file in order to hide the error messages.

---

## Configuration file

```
#$export HAPROXY=/scratch_globa/HAProxy/haproxy-1.5.12-dist

global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        user    test
        group   test_1
        maxconn 8890
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull

#
#  Listen on *:80 - Send traffic to the backend named "apache"
#
frontend www-http
    bind *:8890
    default_backend virtuoso

#
# Back-end definition.
#
backend virtuoso
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    server node0 xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8890 check
# 

#############################################
# Start
```

Comment: Is it showing it in a log file or to your console?

Comment: Console. Actually all the users on the server are getting this message lol it's spamming the whole sever lolololol. Every TIme I turn off virtuoso or something wrong happens then this error message is shown. The problem is that all the users that are on the server are getting this message it is annoying them lolll

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The post to referenced in your question is right, you need to tell rsyslog (or syslog) to stop sending `local0.emerg` and `local1.emerg` messages to the console.

You'd need to append those lines to `rsyslog.conf`, not the HAProxy config file.

As an alternative, you could change

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
```

to

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0 info alert
    log /dev/log    local1 notice alert
```

This will have the effect of "capping" the maximum severity of messages to `alert`, as outlined in the HAProxy [docs](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-log):

```
log <address> [len <length>] <facility> [<level> [<minlevel>]]  

...

<level>    is optional and can be specified to filter outgoing messages. By
           default, all messages are sent. If a level is specified, only
           messages with a severity at least as important as this level
           will be sent. An optional minimum level can be specified. If it
           is set, logs emitted with a more severe level than this one will
           be capped to this level. This is used to avoid sending "emerg"
           messages on all terminals on some default syslog configurations.
           Eight levels are known :
             emerg  alert  crit   err    warning notice info  debug
```

Comment: If I raise Local1 for example to Local2 what will change?

Comment: As this site is for professional sysadmins, I would think you'd know where to find `rsyslog.conf`, or at the vert least, *how* to find it. No, changing `local1` to `local2` won't do anything to fix your issue. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Originator_provides) Wikipedia article to find out why.

Comment: It worked sheesh you saved my life